# PHP global variables across files

Tags: php, global

Ok, maybe my brain is just shut off, but I can't get this to work.

Here's the complete code:

Page1.php:

```
<?php
    $something = "hello";
    include "Page2.php";
?>
```

Page2.php:

```
<?php
    echo $something;
?>
```

Desired output (when navigating to Page1.php):

```
hello
```

The real output is blank. I have tried putting the global keyword everywhere, and nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: Global is within the scope of the linked/included files running from the page called. Two different pages called at separate times don't share variables. If that were the case, by default, it would be nightmare.

Comment: *The pages are not called at separate times*

Comment: I think it means he is 'hitting' Page1.php with his browser.

Comment: I don't know why I missed that. Stargazer, you might try require() instead and see if you get an error. Your path may be different than you think.

Comment: What does `print_r($GLOBALS)` in Page2.php show? If the variable was set at all, but is blank for some reason, it would show up in the array somewhere at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot replicate this error, just tried this on my localhost and copied and pasted your code from here. I suspect you have some sort of syntax error.

Turn on error reports and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Amazing. I should not have named them page1 and page2. I had page2 bookmarked by mistake. +1 for being 1 of only 2 people who actually read the code :)

Comment: Hey, we all make mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but I'm trying to do something similar. First of all, when you echo something you still have to put it in " ".  Php will recognize it as a variable as long as you put the $.

Second, you're including page2.php in page1.  Fantastic, but page2 does not recognize $something. Now, if you do it the other way, declare $something in page2, and then call it from page 1 after including it, it will run.

Modifying the variable would require something else...

Comment: Wrong on both counts. The variable $something is a string, and thus needs no additional conversion. As to your second point, a simple test proves that it works: http://etc.caffeineoncode.com/Page1.php

Answer (score 1):

I think the output is coming in page2.php . Am i right? this is because you are echoing a unset variable in page2.php you need to change the following data in order to make it work.
page1.php

```
<?php
include("page2.php");
echo $something;
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$something="Hello";
?>
```

If you will use it and navigate the page 1.php then the output will be Hello

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running on local (Windows) where the values of an array did not follow past the include within the same process.

After switching the include path from *`http://localhost/www/example.php`* to *`C:/www/example.php`*, it works fine now.